# Use WP_User_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php file  for fetching the user details from the wordpress database.
for that I've coded like this

> `$users = new WP_User_Query( array(
>                           'meta_query' => array(
>                               'relation' => 'OR',
>                               array(
>                                   'key'     => 'first_name',
>                                   'value'   => '',
>                                   'compare' => 'LIKE'
>                               ),
>                               array(
>                                   'key'     => 'last_name',
>                                   'value'   => '',
>                                   'compare' => 'LIKE'
>                               )
>                           )
>                       ) );
>                       $$result = $users->get_results();`
>
>   
>   echo "   **Roll No**
>   **Name** **Address**
>   **Stream** **Status**";
>   
>   while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {   
>       echo "";
>       echo "$data[0]";
>       echo "$data[1]";
>       echo "$data[2]";
>       echo "$data[3]";
>       echo "$data[4]";
>       echo ""; } echo ""; ?>

but it shows error  that **Fatal error: Class 'WP_User_Query' not found in C:\wamp\www....** how do solve this , help me

Answer (score 1):

You're running this too early context — the class isn't loaded yet.

Try running your code on the `wp_loaded` hook, e.g.:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', function() {
  // code goes here
});
```

Comment: can you make it clear , actually I am new to wordpress

Comment: Done, but if I may… if you couldn't make sense of the original answer methinks you've a ton of reading to do or should team up with a coder who does, lest you'll end up creating security problems and steaming piles of bugs for your client(s).

Comment: now it shows error  "Call to undefined function add_action()"

Comment: Are you even working inside wordpress theme/plugin ?

Comment: That means you're not placing your code in a theme or plugin, or are doing something utterly wrong along those lines. You need to read up on WordPress and its APIs.

Comment: my php file is in same theme directory.